# SBT doesnt care of scalaversion

Tags: scala, compilation, sbt

I have a problem, I want to build my scala project with sbt.
I have scala 2.11.8, `sbt about` print

```
[info] Loading project definition from /home/xxx
[info] Set current project to base (in build file:/home/xxx)
[info] This is sbt 0.13.8
[info] The current project is {file:/home/xxx}
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.11.8
[info] 
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.4
```

but still, when I run `sbt compile` I have exception with :

```
[error]     during phase: typer
[error]     library version: version 2.10.4
[error]     compiler version: version 2.10.4
```

can someone help me?
Thanks

**EDIT** Forgot build.sbt file

build.sbt

```
name := "myproject"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "io.jvm.uuid" %% "scala-uuid" % "0.2.1",
  "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "1.0.4",
  "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.6" % "test",
  "com.github.nscala-time" %% "nscala-time" % "2.12.0",
  "ch.qos.logback" %  "logback-classic" % "1.1.7",
  "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.4.0",
  "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml" % "1.0.4",
  "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.13.0" % "test"
)
```

I don't have any build.scala for this project

Comment: post your build.sbt/scala files

Comment: Sorry, done. I dont have any build.scala so edited with my build.sbt

Comment: Try `sbt reload`. Was it previously set to 2.10.4?

Comment: I think you are confusing the version of scala in which SBT runs and version of scala in which SBT compiles your code against.

Comment: Like @pedrofurla said, you are probably seeing a problem from building the sbt compiler infrastructure itself (sbt uses Scala 2.10 for compilation). What sbt version are you using? If unsure, make sure you have `project/build.properties` with contents such as `sbt.version=0.13.11` to use the latest sbt version.

Comment: My ```project/build.properties``` contains ```sbt.version=0.13.8```, but changing it to ```0.13.11``` doesn't change anything. An ```sbt reload``` don't fix the problem either. I know that sbt is built over scala 2.10 but I thought that the error thrown by sbt at the compilation showed me the compiler version used to build the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Fedora 23. I initially installed sbt with the bintray repository. I had to remove it and re install sbt without the bintray repo.
I was not working so I re-re installed sbt avec bintray repository and it works. Some configuration somewhere was messed up I think...